# How to use generics in dart。

Tags: dart, generics, interface

I use generics in java usually with interface. I want to use generics like java. what should I do. I think use dynamic can not solve my issues.

Comment: Have you read the Dart language tour about the topic? https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics . If so, can you be more specific about what problem you have.

Comment: Given that generics exist under the same name and very similar syntax, it seems you did not really do any research. If you have and you have a *specific* question you are stuck on, feel free to edit your question with your specific problem and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```dart
/// To make an interface in Dart you can create an abstract class.
///
/// Then you can define a generic type with <T>.
///
/// In this sample I'm using <T extends Object> to ensure
/// that I'm not passing a nullable type (such as String?).
abstract class MyInterface<T extends Object> {
  T get myValue;
}

/// Then you can implement your interface like this.
class MyInterfaceImplementation implements MyInterface<String> {
  @override
  final String myValue;
  
  MyInterfaceImplementation(this.myValue);
}
```

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=48e878858553e7111cacfa8d31ce42ce)